# Primefaces: Right align Exporters on table header

Tags: primefaces, datatable, exporter

I delacred the paginatorTemplate of p:dataTable as this:

```
<p:dataTable id="lazyDataTable" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {Exporters}">
```

With declaration of "Exporters":

```
<f:facet name="{Exporters}">
    <h:commandLink>
        <p:graphicImage libray ="images" name="excel.png"/>
        <p:dataExporter type = "xls" target="lazyDataTable" fileName="report" />
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:commandLink>
        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png"/>
        <p:dataExporter type = "pdf" target="lazyDataTable" fileName="report" />
    </h:commandLink>
</f:facet>
```

I want the Exporters will be right aligned of the table header, but it appeared at the middle of the header like this:
[image]

How can I align it to the right of the header, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data exporter in the table header is wrapped into a `<a />`-tag, thus you are able to align the position of the exporter via CSS like this:

```
/*  data-exporter symbol shown in the upper right
    corner of the datatable */

.ui-paginator a, .exporter .ui-datatable-header a {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: In the end it is all html, css, javascript. So with a browser developer tool, these things are fairly easy to find out